# rosserial_python: Serial port read failure

Tags: python, arduino, ros

I have followed the tutorials for setting up the [Arduino IDE](http://wiki.ros.org/rosserial_arduino/Tutorials/Arduino%20IDE%20Setup) and loaded the [Hello World sketch](http://wiki.ros.org/rosserial_arduino/Tutorials/Hello%20World) to my Arduino.

When I run:

```
rosrun rosserial_python serial_node.py /dev/ttyUSB0
```

I get:

```
[INFO] [WallTime: 1461790180.244609] ROS Serial Python Node
[INFO] [WallTime: 1461790180.250091] Connecting to /dev/ttyUSB0 at 57600 baud
[WARN] [WallTime: 1461790182.835996] Serial Port read returned short (expected 72 bytes, received 60 instead).
[WARN] [WallTime: 1461790182.836598] Serial Port read failure: 
[INFO] [WallTime: 1461790182.837084] Packet Failed :  Failed to read msg data
[INFO] [WallTime: 1461790182.837400] msg len is 8
[ERROR] [WallTime: 1461790183.831731] Tried to publish before configured, topic id 125
```

which repeats.

At one time this had worked, but I don't remember what has changed. I uninstalled all ROS components and reinstalled everything following the tutorials, but the problem persists.

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 with ROS Indigo and arduino-1.6.8

If it matters, I am using a virtualenv and had to pip install pyserial and rospkg.  That was not mentioned in the tutorials.

Comment: Does the arduino just spit out a steady stream of values via serial as soon as it's turned on? If so, you could debug using a serial monitor or `screen /dev/ttyUSB0 57600` and try out different baud rates.

Comment: When I try different baud rates from the command line starting serial_node.py, the error is "unable to sync" with the device.  So I think it's using the right baud rate and that the problem is something else.

Comment: Did you try increasing the timeout in [SerialClient Source code](http://docs.ros.org/diamondback/api/rosserial_python/html/SerialClient_8py_source.html) (line 199) to something higher ?